# Customer Directive with Angular Material and controllerAs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I'm testing out Angular Material and I'm trying to use with a custom directive but it seems to not want to respect my binding of vm = this. Here's an example of what I'm trying.

**HTML**

```
<md-button ng-click="vm.test()">vm.Test</md-button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('sidenav.directive', ['ngMaterial'])
    .directive('sidenav', sidenav);

  function sidenav() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'app/components/sidenav/sidenav.directive.html',
      restrict: 'EA',
      controller: SidenavController,
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      bindToController: true
    };
  }

  SidenavController.$inject = ['album', '$scope', 'authenticated', '$location', '$mdSidenav'];
  function SidenavController(albumFactory, $scope, authenticated, $location, $mdSidenav) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.test = function () {
      console.log('vm fired');
    };
  }
})();
```

The click event won't fire. However if I replace the `vm` in the controller with `$scope` and use just `ng-click="test()"` the button works. Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to add a scope to the directive, updated:

```
function sidenav() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'app/components/sidenav/sidenav.directive.html',
    restrict: 'EA',
    controller: SidenavController,
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    bindToController: true,
    scope: {
      vm: '='
    }
  };
}
```